# Font setting for a specific gtk application

Tags: fonts, gtk, settings, gtk3

I want to set the font to be used by **a particular** Gtk+ 3 application. How can it be done?

I know I can set the font to be used by **all** Gtk+ 3 applications in the file `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`, but I do not know how the font can be set for only a specific application.

Edit: I am not developing the application. I just want to run it with a font size different from the current one set for the desktop.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`GtkCssProvider`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html). You don't say what language you're using GTK in, so no code example, but here are the steps:

- create a `GtkCssProvider`
- add a CSS string to it (such as `*{font-family:'Comic Sans';}`) with `gtk_css_provider_load_from_data()`
- activate it with `gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen()`. (You probably want to use the default screen, `gdk_screen_get_default()`.)

Comment: I am not developing the application. I just want to run it with a different font size.

Comment: You might get better answers at Super User in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` according to your wishes for your specific application (i.e. font, font-size, theme, etc.).

Save it under `~/.config/somewhereelse/gtk-3.0`.

Run the application with `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$HOME/.config/somewhereelse your-application`