# Increase Gtk application font size

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygtk

I have a Gtk application, but the font size is quite small and I want to make it bigger. For specific widgets, I increase the font size using CSS, so I tried the following to increase all the font sizes in my application:

```
* {
   font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

However, this seems to trigger recursive behaviour, increasing the text size to such a point that half a letter fits on my screen.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795957/font-setting-for-a-specific-gtk-application) solution, but I cannot find the `settings.ini` file that is mentioned and so cannot edit it.

All other solutions I found were either applied to the all GTK applications (which is not my goal) or they were very old solutions from 2009.

Any ideas how I can still do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that defining the size of an M in terms of the size of an M would trigger recursive behaviour. Try setting it in terms of a fixed unit like pixels instead.